# python 3でpipからNumPyがインストールできない。

Tags: python

ローカルにpython2.7が入っていたのですがpython3を使いたいためhomebrewを用いpython3をインストールしました。
　そしてNumPyをインストールしようと

```
$ pip3 install numpy
```

と実行したら以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
.
.

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 293, in check_types
    "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3s/sq3306n57rgf5539s6bw67qm0000gn/T/pip-build-b_r_jvk6/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/3s/sq3306n57rgf5539s6bw67qm0000gn/T/pip-vjiol_uu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3s/sq3306n57rgf5539s6bw67qm0000gn/T/pip-build-b_r_jvk6/numpy
```

python-devをインストールすればいいのかと思い調べてみたのですが、インストール方法がよくわかりませんでした。

環境はmac,python3.5です。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [pip3 install numpy fails on Python 3.5 · Issue #43916](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/43916)

Answer (score 2):

コメントの[リンク](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/43916)を参考に

```
brew install homebrew/python/numpy --with-python3
```

で無事インストールできました。ありがとうございました。